# Build Failure message displayed when i try to run mvn clean install. Although the .jar files are present in library(.m2 repository)

Tags: java, maven, build-error

I tried the following steps already-
1.Added the dependency in pom.xml 
2.Clean and build project.
3. Maven ->Update Project
4. mvn clean install.
Still the error persist.Please help.

I have added an image which shows that this jar files are present in the maven dependencies. I added them manually.

[image]

Dependencies in pom.xml-

```
<dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jettison/jettison -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
```

The error on console-

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CreateProjectMyNextHire 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.2/gson-2.8.2.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-json/1.8/jersey-json-1.8.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-context/3.0.2.RELEASE/spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/3.0.2.RELEASE/spring-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/3.0.2.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-3.0.2.RELEASE.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-tx/3.0.2.RELEASE/spring-tx-3.0.2.RELEASE.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.0.2.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.1/jettison-1.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.620 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-14T19:24:17+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/153M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project CreateProjectMyNextHire: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sgt.pwt:CreateProjectMyNextHire:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17: Failed to read artifact descriptor for log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17: Could not transfer artifact log4j:log4j:pom:1.2.17 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: which java version are you using ?

Comment: i'm using java 1.7

Comment: I also faced this problem. I updated the Java to 1.8 and it fixed the problem.